# Coloring trees : which is the average size of a connected same color area?

Tags: combinatorics

Give a tree with n vertices, the vertices are randomly colored with two equiprobable colors. Thus, connected hoods of the same color are formed.

1) Which is the average size of such a neighborhood?

2) Which is the average size of such a neighborhood that contains a special vertex V ?

If the tree is a linear one, the size of a neighborhood is almost 2. A pointed neighborhood has a size of almost 3.

While trying to solve it, I had the impression that the same sizes are valid for any tree.

Comment: What do you mean by "area"? I would have thought the area of a tree is zero, because it's one-dimensional. What do you mean by a "block"?

Comment: start from a vertex, e.g. e red one. Take his red neighbors then the red neighbor of red neighbors, etc. I really do not know an official name for this. Could it be a "red hood" ? if the tree is linear, the hood is a block.

Comment: If the tree is a star, the center vertex will be in a neighborhood of size $\frac{n+1}{2}$ on average.